# ich kann Skat online nicht installieren - Tastatur wohl gesperrt

Tags: live-usb

wenn ich im Terminal den Befehl :  sudo ./install-skat-online-XX.bin, verlangt Linux anschließen das Passwort-- aber die Tastatur reagiert nicht mehr ??   kann jemand helfen ?

Comment: English only site.

Comment: The website clearly states 3 fairly easy steps. (1) Download (2) make executable (3) run install tool. Which part do you struggle with? Please clearly tell us what you did already (including the commands), and maybe add some output like `ls -l`, etc.

Comment: Zeige biite `uname  -a` show us please `uname  -a`

Comment: Please keep in mind this site is English-speaking only. Try to translate your question and replies to English to the best of your abilities, e.g. with help of an online translation tool. Alternatively, there are also German speaking communities out there. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Download the bin for your architecture and run from terminal:

```
chmod +x install-skat-online-XX.bin
sudo ./install-skat-online-XX.bin
# and to start Skat:
skatonline
```

Comment: was ist denn die Architektur  ??   Terminel ??   dort kann ich chmod eingeben, aber dann mein Passwort nicht mehr

Comment: Architecture is 64 or 32 bit, i don't know the default password from Ubuntu studio, you can try with `Ubuntu`

Comment: die Tastatur schreibt nicht nachdem ich den Befehl chmod....  eingegeben habe --- verlangt Passwort -- aber Tastatur geht nicht

Comment: @Detlev sudo has in default config no echo, you write but you don't see it.

Comment: schreibt :  Datei oder Verzeichniss nicht gefunden

Comment: Did you download the bin? if yes write chmod +x <DOWNLOADED_FILE>

Comment: die Datei ist auf dem Schreibtisch-- ( Desktop )   und im Download Ordner vom Edge für Linux-- aber er kann die Datei nicht finden

Comment: Please english only. Use e.g.  [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator) to translate if you don't speak english.